# B = 注意させないと vs D = 注意してくれないと - Why is B wrong and D correct?

Tags: meaning

> すると、そのお母さんは「自転車で歩道を走らないで。」と言いました。_______困ると言いたそうな顔で、彼女は私を睨みました。
>
> - A 注意させられないと
> - B 注意させないと
> - C 注意してあげないと
> - D 注意してくれないと

I chose B because B means FORCED (させ) and HAVE TO BE CAREFUL ないと  BUT it was wrong, D is the correct answer, why is B wrong and D right?

Also for the そう, there are 2 meanings, one if you heard it from someone and second it seems like.   The seems one has to be at the end of a verb stem and the Head it from has to be after the verb, why is this one after the verb meaning it is the HEARD it from someone?

Comment: Who said this そう has the "heard" meaning? And what do you think the original sentence means? I don't understand why you thought the meaning of "forced" was contained in the original Japanese sentence.

Comment: @naruto   verb dictionary form/past tense (しまう・しまった） + そうだ = 伝言(Report speech) I heard ~

新完全マスター
今、テレビの天気予報で見たんだけど、明日は全国的に雨だそうだよ。

Comment: Of course I know that, but 言いた is by no means a dictionary form. (That's why we are asking for your translation attempt...)

Comment: @fynxgloire that's completely uncalled for. And as was pointed out, 言いた is neither dictionary form nor past tense.

Answer (score 5):

First, this そう has the meaning of "seems/looks" because it follows the stem of 言いたい. ～と言いたそうな顔で literally means "with a face that seems to want to say ～". 言いた is not a dictionary form of anything. Just in case, the past form of 言う is not 言いた but 言った.

Second, in case you missed this, そのお母さん is not "this mom" but "this ma'am" in a context like this. She's basically a stranger.

So this madam was upset and glared at 私 as if to say *something*. What's the thing the madam wanted to say? Since D is the correct answer, the content of 言う, marked with と, is:

> 注意してくれないと困る

This doesn't have any explicit subject, but in this context, you need to be able to infer the subjects like this:

> **(あなたが)** 注意してくれないと **(私は)** 困る
> If **you** don't pay attention <sub>(for the sake of me)</sub>, **I** am bothered!
> → It bothers me if you don't pay attention!

くれる indicates the subject of 注意する is someone other than お母さん.

> 注意してくれないと困ると言いたそうな顔で、彼女は私を睨みました。
>
> (literally, with direct speech) She glared at me with a face that seemed to want to say "If you don't pay attention, I will be bothered".
>
> (with indirect speech) She glared at me as if to say she would be bothered if I wasn't more careful.

B is incorrect because no causative form is relevant in this sentence. 注意させないと困る would mean "If I won't make her/you pay attention, I will be troubled (in the future)", but no one would say something like this directly to a stranger they won't see again.

Answer (score 0):

The first clue to choosing the correct expression to go in the blank is to note that "that mother" is the topic of the sentence because it is marked with は

> そのお母さんは

So, unless another *actor/subject* is explicitly expressed, the mother's actions and thoughts are being expressed here.

The next clue is the verb 困る.  Something is potentially going to *annoy* this mother.

Given these two clues, choices *A* and *B* make no sense in that position.  Whatever verb you fill in here needs to retain "mother" as the subject.  Choices *A* and *B* would seem to require 私 as the subject.  It is not natural to switch the subject of the verb like that in the middle of a sentence.

But this is particularly true given the next clue

> __困ると言いたそうな顔

You questioned the meaning of そう.  This cannot be the *hearsay* そう because the grammar is incorrect for that form.  If you wanted the *hearsay* そう then the grammar would need to be

> __困ると言いたいそうな顔

But that really makes absolutely no sense

> A face that I hear wants to say she'll be upset if ...

What's being described is a scene in which the mother is *lecturing **me***.  I don't require "hearsay" to see the expression on her face.

So, the only two choices that make any potential sense are choices *C* and *D*.

*C* takes the wrong perspective.
So, the only answer that works is *D*.  Keep in mind that くれる  takes the perspective of the subject being quoted.  Here one is quoting the mother's perspective--what the mother is "saying" by her facial expression.  Only in choice *D* is it stated clearly that if you don't heed this mother's admonishment she'll be upset.

Comment: The subject of くれる is 私, just like that of あげる. In addition, あげる (literally meaning “*to raise*”) doesn’t suggest someone in a *superior* position is giving something to someone *below* them. The reason くれる is the correct choice is that the subject of 言う is the mother and the quoted part is said from her perspective as the beneficiary of the action 注意する. How the speaker refers to the mother is irrelevant.

Comment: @aguijonazo I am confused about あげる.  Now I'm scratching my head.  I thought saying something like 社長にあげました was considered improper.  What am I thinking of then?

Comment: @aguijonazo I understand what you're saying about くれる and 私 and agree.  But, I'm not sure how to talk about it because this 私 you're referring to is the mother, not me (the speaker).  We've got two 私's in a sense.

Comment: I refer to the speaker by 私. The speaker is the one who takes the action of 注意する regardless of whether it is followed by くれる or あげる. You say してあげる when someone takes some action for a third person. してくれる is different in that you (as the speaker) are the beneficiary. The action is taken by the same person.